# How to send email Notification with Suject in Azure Databricks using Databricks CLI?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have created Python script to send email notification as below

```
"email_notifications":{
           'on_failure':''
                  }
```

How I can include this in my subject?

Answer (score 0):

Right now for jobs configuration the notification format is not modifiable right now.